# Intellij: Ignore warnings by file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, suppress-warnings

as many others I have the problem that Intellij throws some warnings, that are not relevant to me. I can of course go through everyone of them and let Intellij insert the suppresswarning-tag. But I am wondering whether there is a more elegant way to do this.

When working with Pylint (Python Code Inspection) there was a pylint.rc file, where warnings could be suppressed. This does not only have the advantage that I have all the warnings I suppressed in one location, but also that I can simply copy this file to other projects and reuse it.

Is there a similar way for Intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change setting of [Code Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-inspection.html)

When you open `Analyze/Inspect code...` you can see and change your `inspection profiles` and disable warnings what your want. Also you can do import and export your `inspection profile`.

[image]

> **Inspection profiles**
>
> When you inspect your code, you can tell IntelliJ IDEA which types of
>   problems you would like to search for and get reports about. Such
>   configurations can be preserved as inspection profiles.
>
> An inspection profile defines the types of problems to be sought for,
>   i.e. which code inspections are enabled/disabled and the severity of
>   these inspections. Profiles are configurable in the Inspections
>   settings page.
>
> To set the current inspection profile (the one that is used for the
>   on-the-fly code analysis in the editor), simply select it in the
>   Inspections settings page and apply changes. When you perform code
>   analysis or execute a single inspection, you can specify which profile
>   to use for each run.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was searching for!